# How to Change Mobile fonts mean install custom fonts, to system

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, system-font

How to change or install custom fonts to the Android device, 
What class or method is usable in custom Launchers that change the system fonts, of an android device,

Comment: Ordinary apps cannot do that, sorry.

Comment: Is there any source or information link about this topic?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a clear cut place (that I could find at least) where it states you can't do it. However, a google search on [how to set custom font android](https://www.google.pt/search?q=how+to+set+custom+system+font+android&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=yBteWrm6HIHAUvCbg4AM) leads you to two, and only two ways:

- Root it
- Use a custom launcher

Again, while this doesn't prove anything, it seems suspicious there isn't any reference to another way, however obscure it may be.

p.S.: I'd post this as a comment but I don't have enough rep yet and it doesn't seem toooo misplaced as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) Right-click the res folder and go to New > Android resource directory. The New Resource Directory window appears.

2) In the Resource type list, select font, and then click OK.

3) The name of the resource directory must be font.

4) Add your font files in the font folder.

Comment: I am asking about System Fonts not app fonts,