# How to install a system font programmatically on a Samsung Android device?

Tags: android, fonts, samsung-mobile, system-font

As I understand it, [it is not possible to set a custom font as a system font in standard Android devices that have not been rooted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31071976/3681880). However, [I hear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36279746/3681880) that it is possible to do on devices from certain manufacturers, like Samsung. So I would like to know how to install a bundled font from my app as a system font if the user has a Samsung phone. Or even if I can't install it directly, how do I make the font available for the user to go into settings to choose it? This is apparently possible since such functionality is provided by [iFont](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kapp.ifont) and other apps.

#### Notes

I am not asking [how to use use a custom font in my own app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49744799/3681880).

I am not asking how to set a custom system font generally in Android.

- [How to install custom font in android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051915/how-to-install-custom-font-in-android-device)
- [Android Device install new font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421741/android-device-install-new-font)
- [android - setup and install Custom Font in Android without root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279342/android-setup-and-install-custom-font-in-android-without-root)
- [android - install font to android platform without root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996621/android-install-font-to-android-platform-without-root)
- [How to Change Mobile fonts mean install custom fonts, to system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284113/how-to-change-mobile-fonts-mean-install-custom-fonts-to-system)

I am asking specifically how to do it on a Samsung device.

Comment: probably you could reverse-engineer iFont app to see how they do it. I don't think that there is an open API for changing system font in Android. It is kind of security issue. Imagine that you build your custom font, and change it's letters the way that `Reset to factory state` in settings menu will look like `Turn on WIFI` for example. This could harm user information, right?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, right. Even Samsung doesn't allow that type of settings change, but they apparently do allow custom fonts to be installed.

Comment: When they allow to install custom font, it means that the user knows what he is doing, and he really wants to install it. But if 3rd-party app could do it, it doesn't mean that user wants it.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I presume the process is similar to installing a custom keyboard. You provide the font as an option in a list, but the user must explicitly open settings and choose the font themselves.