# Prevent custom system fonts overriding app fonts

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Devices like `Samsung` allows users to set `custom system fonts`. Issue is that those fonts can be overriding my app `fonts`. I mean if I set `Arial` `font` in my app and I've set `Calibri` font as `system font` on my mobile then `Arial` will be overridden by the `Calibri font`.

How to prevent this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - "If you need to set one font for all `TextView's` in your `Android`
>     application you can use this solution.
> - It will override **ALL**
>     `TextView's` typefaces, including the `Action Bar`, **custom system
>     fonts** and other standard components, but `EditText's` password font
>     won't be overridden." (For obvious reasons).
> - Using [`reflection`](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/learn-java-for-android-development-reflection-basics--mobile-3203) to override default typeface and the [`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) class.
> - NOTE: DO NOT FORGET TO SET TYPEFACE FOR APP THEME AS DEFAULT TYPEFACE WHICH WILL BE OVERRIDDEN

**MyApp.java**:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SERIF", "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"); // font from assets: "assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
  }
}
```

**res/themes.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- you should set typeface which you want to override with TypefaceUtil -->
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**TypefaceUtil.java**:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class TypefaceUtil {

    /**
     * Using reflection to override default typeface
     * NOTICE: DO NOT FORGET TO SET TYPEFACE FOR APP THEME AS DEFAULT TYPEFACE WHICH WILL BE OVERRIDDEN
     * @param context to work with assets
     * @param defaultFontNameToOverride for example "monospace"
     * @param customFontFileNameInAssets file name of the font from assets
     */
    public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
        try {
            final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);

            final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Can not set custom font " + customFontFileNameInAssets + " instead of " + defaultFontNameToOverride);
        }
    }
}
```

**assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf:**

Put *your* font here e.g. `Arial`.

[ref1](https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/7749076)

Author [Artem Zinnatullin](https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin)

Comment: As far as I've understood the solution, I must first recognize the font which I want to override with my font. My app will go commercial and I can't recognize which font the user will be using as custom system font.

Comment: No. You can get the default [Typeface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) using `font_title = Typeface.DEFAULT;` You can also get the default Typeface based on specified style: `Typeface.defaultFromStyle(int style)` See also [how-to-install-a-system-font-programmatically-on-a-samsung-android-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850865/how-to-install-a-system-font-programmatically-on-a-samsung-android-device)

Comment: Ok I will give it another try and will let you know